# c++ listen to modifications on a network drive - windows

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, shared-directory

I am trying to run this code in CodeBlocks to listen to the modifications in a folder but I get an error. I`m totally new in this so I have no ideea what is going on...

The code was taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/obtaining-directory-change-notifications

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
void RefreshDirectory(LPTSTR);
void RefreshTree(LPTSTR);
void WatchDirectory(LPTSTR);

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: %s <dir>\n"), argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    WatchDirectory(argv[1]);
}

void WatchDirectory(LPTSTR lpDir)
{
   DWORD dwWaitStatus;
   HANDLE dwChangeHandles[2];
   TCHAR lpDrive[4];
   TCHAR lpFile[_MAX_FNAME];
   TCHAR lpExt[_MAX_EXT];

   _tsplitpath_s(lpDir, lpDrive, 4, NULL, 0, lpFile, _MAX_FNAME, lpExt, _MAX_EXT);

   lpDrive[2] = (TCHAR)'\\';
   lpDrive[3] = (TCHAR)'\0';

 // Watch the directory for file creation and deletion.

   dwChangeHandles[0] = FindFirstChangeNotification(
  lpDir,                         // directory to watch
  FALSE,                         // do not watch subtree
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME); // watch file name changes

   if (dwChangeHandles[0] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
     printf("\n ERROR: FindFirstChangeNotification function failed.\n");
     ExitProcess(GetLastError());
   }

// Watch the subtree for directory creation and deletion.

   dwChangeHandles[1] = FindFirstChangeNotification(
  lpDrive,                       // directory to watch
  TRUE,                          // watch the subtree
  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME);  // watch dir name changes

   if (dwChangeHandles[1] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
     printf("\n ERROR: FindFirstChangeNotification function failed.\n");
     ExitProcess(GetLastError());
   }


// Make a final validation check on our handles.

   if ((dwChangeHandles[0] == NULL) || (dwChangeHandles[1] == NULL))
   {
     printf("\n ERROR: Unexpected NULL from FindFirstChangeNotification.\n");
 ExitProcess(GetLastError());
   }

// Change notification is set. Now wait on both notification
// handles and refresh accordingly.

   while (TRUE)
   {
   // Wait for notification.

  printf("\nWaiting for notification...\n");

  dwWaitStatus = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, dwChangeHandles,
     FALSE, INFINITE);

  switch (dwWaitStatus)
  {
     case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

     // A file was created, renamed, or deleted in the directory.
     // Refresh this directory and restart the notification.

         RefreshDirectory(lpDir);
         if ( FindNextChangeNotification(dwChangeHandles[0]) == FALSE )
         {
           printf("\n ERROR: FindNextChangeNotification function failed.\n");
           ExitProcess(GetLastError());
         }
         break;

     case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:

     // A directory was created, renamed, or deleted.
     // Refresh the tree and restart the notification.

         RefreshTree(lpDrive);
         if (FindNextChangeNotification(dwChangeHandles[1]) == FALSE )
         {
           printf("\n ERROR: FindNextChangeNotification function failed.\n");
           ExitProcess(GetLastError());
         }
         break;

     case WAIT_TIMEOUT:

     // A timeout occurred, this would happen if some value other
     // than INFINITE is used in the Wait call and no changes occur.
     // In a single-threaded environment you might not want an
     // INFINITE wait.

        printf("\nNo changes in the timeout period.\n");
        break;

     default:
        printf("\n ERROR: Unhandled dwWaitStatus.\n");
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
        break;
     }
   }
}

void RefreshDirectory(LPTSTR lpDir)
{
   // This is where you might place code to refresh your
   // directory listing, but not the subtree because it
   // would not be necessary.

   _tprintf(TEXT("Directory (%s) changed.\n"), lpDir);
}

void RefreshTree(LPTSTR lpDrive)
{
   // This is where you might place code to refresh your
   // directory listing, including the subtree.

   _tprintf(TEXT("Directory tree (%s) changed.\n"), lpDrive);
 }
```

The error I get is:

```
`_tsplitpath_s` was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Ran your code with the argument C:\Temp\. When changing a file in that directory it does tell. No error from _tsplitpath_s declaration.

Comment: @peakpeak can you clarify please?

Comment: Your code works as it should

Comment: @peakpeak I am trying to build and run it in CodeBlocks, should I install sth else? is the compiler the one that gives me that error?

Comment: How exactly should I run it to make it work?

Comment: I run it in Visual Studio 2017 Community. No errors